# Why can't I add layers on top of ol-mapbox-style?

Tags: openlayers

I have a map that has several layers and I'm trying to upgrade the baselayer to use mapbox styles, but the mapbox layer seems to always render on top of the other layer. Is there a way to make the mapbox layer a base layer and still allow layering on top of it?

Here's a simple codepen example: https://codepen.io/eflowbeach/pen/abqMBwO

```
olms.apply(map, 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/4f4843d99c34436f82920932317893ae/resources/styles/root.json?f=json');

// This gets hidden under the vector tile layer, you can briefly see it load
var test = new ol.layer.WebGLTile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      });
map.addLayer(test);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

olms returns a promise which resolves when it completes.  Wait for it to resolve before adding further layers

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([-90, 45], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
    zoom: 4
  })
});

olms(
  map,
  "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/4f4843d99c34436f82920932317893ae/resources/styles/root.json?f=json"
).then(function () {
  var test = new ol.layer.WebGLTile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });
  map.addLayer(test);
});
```

https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/QWQPxEa